# Linked List Operations In C (Segmentation Error Core Dumped!)

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have been trying to implement Linked List operations in c from the past few days, but I keep stumbling upon the same error again and again which says "Segmentation Error Core Dumped". I'm not able to figure out what part of the logic is going wrong. It is strange as after resolving all the warnings and Errors the code just doesn't execute. It would also be great if someone points out to me if I am using a linked list and pointers correctly. My code seems to be huge to post but I just couldn't shorten it out. And again, I would be grateful to all those who can help me out and make this code more readable and reduce the ambiguities.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct nodes 
{
    int data;
    struct nodes* next; 
};
typedef struct nodes* node;
node head=NULL;
void InsertFront()
{
    node temp=NULL;
    printf("Enter The Value Of Node\n");
    scanf("%d",&temp->data);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head->data=temp->data;     
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void InsertBack()
{
    node temp,newnode;
    printf("Enter The Value Of Node\n");`enter code here`
        scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head->data=newnode->data;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        newnode=temp->next;
    }    
}

void InsertPosition()
{
    node previousnode,newnode,nextnode,temp;
    int position,count=0;
    printf("Enter the Position At Which New Node Has To Be Inserted");
    scanf("%d",&position);
    printf("Enter The Value Of Node\n");
    scanf("%d",&newnode->data);
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head->data=newnode->data;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL && count<position);
        {
            previousnode=temp;
            temp=temp->next;
            count=count+1;
            nextnode=temp;
        }
        previousnode->next=newnode;
        newnode->next=nextnode;
    }
}

void DeleteFront()
{
    node temp;
    if(head->next==NULL)
    {
        head==NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        head->next=temp;
        head=NULL;
        head=temp;
    }
}

void DeleteBack()
{
    node temp;
    if(head->next==NULL)
    {
        head==NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
        }
        temp=NULL;
    }
}

void DeletePosition()
{
    node temp,nextnode,deletenode;
    int position,count=0;
    printf("Enter The Position At Which The Node Has To Be Deleted");
    scanf("%d",&position);
    if(head->next==NULL)
    {
        head==NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp=head;
        while(temp->next!=NULL && count!=position)
        {
            temp=temp->next;
            count=count+1;
        }
        deletenode=temp->next;
        nextnode=deletenode->next;
        deletenode->next=NULL;
        temp->next=nextnode;
    }
}

void Display()
{
    node temp;
    temp=head;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        printf("Linked List Seems To Be Empty");
    }
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d -> ",temp->data);
    }

}

int main()
{ 
    int choice;
    printf("\nLINKED LIST OPERATIONS\n\n");
    printf("Select An Option\n1 - Insert From Front\t   2 - Insert From Back\n3 - Insert At 
            A Position   4 - Delete At The Front\n5 - Delete At The Back\t   6 - Delete At A 
            Position\n7 - Display\t           8 - Exit\n\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case(1) :
            {
                InsertFront();
            }
        case(2) :
            {
                InsertBack();
            }
        case(3) :
            {
                InsertPosition();
            }
        case(4) :
            {
                DeleteFront();
            }
        case(5) :
            {
                DeleteBack();
            }
        case(6) :
            {
                DeletePosition();
            }
        case(7) :
            {
                Display();
            }
        case(8) :
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        default :
            {
                printf("Invalid Input\n");
                exit(0);
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't look at all the code, but immediately saw this: `if(head==NULL) { head->data=newnode->data; }`. You are de-referencing a `NULL` pointer. You can't do that.

Comment: How can I edit the code without deferencing  a NULL pointer

Comment: Just advice, try debugging tools for such errors (eg. Valgrind).

Comment: Please clean up your warnings first.  You have some lines like "head==NULL;" which is not what you want.  This will fix some of your issues.

Comment: You probably want: `if (head == NULL) { head = newnode;}`

Comment: Also, in the future, if you want us to take the time to check your code then the least you can do is properly format it. There are online tools to help with this. [prettyprinter](http://prettyprinter.de/index.php) is one example.

Comment: You might also want to look up "c switch case fall through".

Comment: Also, you don't allocate any memory for the nodes. `node newnode;...scanf("%d",&newnode->data);` You are using an uninitialized pointer. See [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) and [`free()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)

Comment: `while(temp->next!=NULL && count<position);
     {`
is a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the cuff, your first function you may want to pass the head pointer as an argument to the function or have the return value be a node* so it is more versatile. Neither the head nor the temp were initialized which happens three ways: You assign an existing variable address to the pointer, you make a malloc call to assign storage, and the third way I cant remember, check out the resources below. They will help! You have allocated a pointer variable by declaring a local and global node*, they are compatible however you have not initialized either of them with a reference to another variable; you have simply declared them. A pointer must be initialized with a reference assignment to another address either from malloc, &addressof, etc. Null simply marks them as bad pointers without throwing a segfault when tested. Think of it like a file name without any storage allocated...You can't save to it but its there. Since neither are initialized, when you try to assign to them, you get a memory error because no storage has been set aside yet. Which means...segfault! There are three components to a pointer superficially: [Pointer address for the alias/named region of storage/object|memory block reserved to hold whatever size you declare you need, in this case, you set that aside as such: head = malloc(sizeof(struct node *)), this allocates most likely an 8 byte address space which points a suitable region of storage->|*dereferenced value of the address the storage is reffering to]
Try running gdb and setting a break on each of the two pointers in your first function. I hope that helps and hope I haven't given you bad advice...

I struggled with these too quite a bit, here are some good resources that will be worth your time:

Stanfor CS Library
-CONCISELY covers pointers, linked lists, binary trees, debugging to find out exactly what line of code is generating your error;
http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/

Comment: Thank you so much pchelper for taking your time out and helping me, I will surely implement everything and check if my code runs smoothly.